# Select the Class and change the value of class without using For loop

Tags: jquery

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   if(("#Selected"+i+".menuClass").value = 'Y')){
      document.getElementById("Menu"+i).checked = true;
      document.getElementById("Menu"+i).value = 'Y';
      SelectedCount += 1;
   }
   //Functions will be added in this place
}
```

In the JSP page I will be show the list of menu. Among that menus only some menus have "menuClass" in it.To find the menu which are all having the "menuClass" "FOR loop" is used.

But inside the loop according to the requirement Function are added. While adding the functions it was reducing the performance of the page. Is there is any method is their to select the Menu which are all having the "menuClass" without FOR loop in it and perform the function for the menus which are all having "menuClass".

Comment: $(".menuClass[value='Y']").each(function(item, index){ //add functions. }) does something like this help you?

Comment: Yes .each(function(){} can be used. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I will add it as an answer so you can close it :-)

Comment: jQuery's [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) is still iterating over the elements, therefore there's still some kind of loop being used internally; but to iterate over any collection of elements there will always be a loop of some form. Incidentally if you show enough of your [mcve] code we can - usually - suggest a better way, such as delegated event-binding which will reduce the number of times a function has to be bound.

Comment: It is, but it is filtered down quite a bit tho.

Comment: From the above answer i got a idea of using $('.menuClass').each(function(){//Functions added} it will be showing only the menu which are all having the "menuClass" in it. Through this we can avoid iterating unnecessary menus.

Comment: @KarthikSubramani but... that's still looping. and is probably slower than using a for loop.

Comment: @KevinB did you down voted my answer? if so, why? if it made it faster for the OP then, why you guys bashing it? i thought the main reason for this site was for help people, apparently i am wrong.

Comment: @Zorkind i don't see either of the answers as being useful (yours or the deleted one). The op asked for something that doesn't use a for loop. jquery's .each [does in fact use a for loop](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L294), and it isn't faster than just using a for loop, so there's no gain.

Comment: well internally it uses a for loop, what you want me to do if it worked for him? all good keep down voting then. it just don't make sense to me.

Comment: It doesn't have to, it's my vote to use, just like you have your votes to do with as you please. They're just votes, nothing to get upset about.

Comment: i think he asked the question in a wrong manner. he admits in his own comment that he wanted a way to filter the data, regardless of looping or not.

Comment: I don't disagree, the question is quite unclear, even including code that is invalid. Fortunately we have a close reason for this type of question

Comment: yes, and i worked it with him to come to see what he really wanted, and i gave it to him. that's all.

Comment: i edited my answer, does it looks better now @KevinB?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the comment the OP made

> From the above answer i got a idea of using $('.menuClass').each(function(){//Functions added} it will be showing only the menu which are all having the "menuClass" in it. Through this we can avoid iterating unnecessary menus. – Karthik Subramani Dec 12 '17 at 13:55

I give him this solution, but it is not consistent with his question, he asked for a way to do it without loop, but in the comments he said he wanted a way to proper filter his menus, regardless of looping or not.

Use `each()`

```
$(".menuClass").each(function(item, index){ //add functions. })
```

To know more about this visit [Jquery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

This way you filter down the amount of elements, you will still be traversing the DOM, but quite less than otherwise, because of the class selector.